# What computer port is this?

Tags: windows, ports

My Lenovo X1 Carbon (6th gen) supposedly has a MicroSD card reader. But I have never had to use a MicroSD card reader before and I couldn't identify this port. I tried to put the microSD card in, but it didn't fit. So, what is this? The flash is a bit strong, but the icon for this port is three squares being connected with lines.

[image: Image of port]

Comment: It's great that you got an answer to your question.  However, identifying ports and similar things from an image is generally off-topic.  Among other reasons, it isn't searchable, which means that it can't be of much help to others with a similar question, which is kind of the purpose of the site.  See for example: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7647/are-hardware-port-cable-etc-visual-identification-questions-allowed-or-not and https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6073/are-guessing-game-type-questions-allowed-on-su.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's used for an ethernet adapter. This range of laptop is too thin to put a full sized RJ-45 port in, so they use this port to extend out.

If you didn't receive one in the box, you should be able to buy one from Lenovo directly.

**Part Name:** ThinkPad Ethernet Extension Adapter Gen 2
**Part Number:** 4X90Q84427
**Product Description:** Converts the special micro Ethernet connector on supported ThinkPad computers to the standard RJ45 connector. Supports PXE boot, Mac Pass Through, and Wake-On-LAN (depends on system capability).

[image: ThinkPad Ethernet Extension Adapter Gen 2]

Here is a link to the product page:

https://www.lenovo.com/nz/en/accessories-and-monitors/cables-and-adapters/adapters/CABLE-BO-Ethernet-Extension-Adapter-2/p/4X90Q84427

---

As for the MicroSD card reader, it should be located under a cover at the back of the laptop, near one of the hinges:

[image: MicroSD Card slot]
[Source](https://www.laptopmain.com/lenovo-thinkpad-x1-carbon-2018-disassembly/)

Comment: This is so silly. We already have USB 3 (10 Gbps), Thunderbolt 3 (40 Gbps), both of which are easily capable of driving gigabit and even 10 gigabit ethernet.  You'll never find a use for a dongle like this outside of Lenevo land, and you can't source it from anywhere else either. There's no need for this proprietary crap.

Comment: @Alexander I'm going to guess this isn't doing any protocol translation from USB to Ethernet, etc. It's just a breakout header for the LAN port directly to whatever the networking circuitry runs on.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the case, but it's not like it made the device any cheaper. It's $38 USD from Lenovo's site, whereas Amazon offers multiple USB 3 to gigabit ethernet adapters for $14-20 (with really good reviews, too).

Comment: @MichaelFrank USB adds CPU overhead - this is very likely direct to ethernet as you suggested.

Comment: @Criggie Arguably, if that extra CPU overhead is important for your ultralight laptop, you're using the wrong computer.

Comment: USB Ethernet Adapters are normally not PXE boot capable. And the  deployment of new Systems is usually done via a PXE deployment System in bigger companies.

Comment: @Sunzi This adapter is actually PXE boot capable, which further leads to my suspicion that it is simply a breakout for the actual ethernet circuit.

Comment: Thanks, the freaking SD card slot was *behind* the hinges... I would have never found it if it wasn't for your description!!!